# macOS & SwiftUI 2: simplest way to turn off beep on keystroke

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard, beep

The following trivial macOS app is written in SwiftUI 2.0.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TempApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup { ContentView() }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, beep!").padding()
  }
}
```

When in the foreground, this app will emit an error beep on certain keystrokes (like "a"). What's the simplest way to suppress this beep?

---

An Xcode project illustrating this (and the answer) can be found [here](https://github.com/claybridges/macOS-SwiftUI-NoBeepOnKeystroke).

---

There are many [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992742) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010745) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869462) on SO, but none of these are specifically about doing this in SwiftUI 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the beep by adding a local monitor for the `.keyDown` event at the top level. This can be done simply in `ContentView.init()`, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, silence!").padding()
  }

  init() {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) { _ in return nil }
  }
}
```

This technique was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519306/45813).